# Meaning of "chosen markets"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have been reviewing view proposals and I came across:

> We state that the Company has been trading successfully in its chosen
>   markets for over twenty years.

What is the meaning of the above sentence?

Why do they say **"Chosen Market"**? Is there a hidden meaning behind this sentence?

Comment: The "chosen markets"  are the markets where the company has decided  to operate or invest. (The markets chosen by the company itself). They may be geographical (China, India etc.) or sectorial, (metals, technology, consumer etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As oozy says, chosen merely indicates that the company has  selected specific markets (be they regional, commodity based, or other) and succeeded in them. The implication is an additional layer of strategic thought where the company has not only invested wisely but carefully chosen where to participate and possibly developed specialized expertise in these markets (expertise being a sought after quality in finance). Basically, they are trying to make it sounds like they know what they are doing and are professional (though you should do your own research to confirm that).